# R - How to parallelize a for loop that does monte carlo simluations?

Tags: r

I am trying to work out how to parallelize some code from "data mining with R - learning with case studies" in order to have it run quicker on my macbook pro. The particular code in question is below. The code basically uses the same data (DSs) and applies six different learners (e.g. svm, nnet for regression and classification etc) with a small number of variants.

The full code is [HERE](http://www.liaad.up.pt/~ltorgo/DataMiningWithR/code3.html) (near the bottom, in the "model evaluation and selection" section).

```
for(td in TODO) {
  assign(td,
     experimentalComparison(
       DSs,         
       c(
         do.call('variants',
                 c(list('singleModel',learner=td),VARS[[td]],
                   varsRootName=paste('single',td,sep='.'))),
         do.call('variants',
                 c(list('slide',learner=td,
                        relearn.step=c(60,120)),
                   VARS[[td]],
                   varsRootName=paste('slide',td,sep='.'))),
         do.call('variants',
                 c(list('grow',learner=td,
                        relearn.step=c(60,120)),
                   VARS[[td]],
                   varsRootName=paste('grow',td,sep='.')))
         ),
        MCsetts)
     )
  # save the results
  save(list=td,file=paste(td,'Rdata',sep='.'))
}
```

Most of the parallelization information I find, seems to be more applicable to things like 'apply', where the same function is applied to different subsets of the data. What this code does, is the opposite - different functions applied the same data.

Would it be better to parallel the outer FOR loop, so that the code within is run for multiple learners at a time, as opposed to parallel the code within the loop so that the different windowing approaches are paralleled for a single learner.

Execution for a single iteration is just over 2 hours on my macbook, where only 2 cores appear to be doing anything (the other two just sit idle). The actual code from the link is set to 20 iterations... It would be great to use my idle cores to reduce this

Comment: For extensive monte carlo simulations R is probably too slow no matter how you parallelize it. An easy way to get a small (1-5 times) speedup is by using the compiler function to bytecompile your main function (e.g. `variantsCMP <- cmpfun(variants)`, but for a much faster speedup you can best use a compiled language. C++ can easily be implemented in R through the `Rcpp` package.

Comment: A quick and dirty way to do parallel computations is to use `lapply(1:N, some_function)`, where `N` is the number of times you want to calculate `some_function`. On Unix/Linux, you can replace `lapply` with `mclapply` from the `parallel` package (assuming you have more than 1 core). If you are on Windows, take a look at the `snow` package.

Comment: So, something like lapply(1:6, code_as_function())? Where the function uses all the global variables as opposed to anything that is passed to it? That would seem to make sense, as the TODO variable, is simply a list of leaner names to apply to the whole data set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the non-parallel case, passing functions into an `lapply` loop is straightforward.

```
lapply(c(mean, sum), function(f) f(1:5))
```

The are a few different systems for parallel programming with R.  This next example uses `snow`.

```
library(snow)
cl <- makeCluster(c("localhost","localhost"), type = "SOCK")
clusterApply(cl, c(mean, sum), function(f) f(1:5))
stopCluster(cl)
```

You should get the same answer in each case!

Comment: I am on mac, so like tahoe california at the moment - no snow

Comment: There's a Mac binary for `snow` on CRAN.  Are you sure it won't work? http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/snow/index.html

Comment: Anyway, which parallel make you use doesn't make a difference to the concept: you want a function like `lapply`, and pass it a list of functions (names of functions will also work).

Comment: Oh... Apologies I thought snow was windows only. I give that a go, once I rw-write the code above

Comment: For picking a parallel package, consider reading www.jstatsoft.org/v31/i01/paper couple of years old, but comprehensive.

Comment: Thanks for the article link. I'll take a read of it. Basically, I'm looking for a 'pattern' of how to parallelize code like the above, which I can reuse over and over in different projects. I'm not looking for uber robustness and speed, more of a convenient speed up